# Finding a net that converges to the zero map in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, nets

I'm looking through Willard's *General Topology* and I came across this problem in the section on nets.

> **Willard 11A.1** In $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, let $E = \{f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} \mid f(x) = 0$ or $1$ and $f(x) = 0$ only finite often$\}$ and let $g$ be the function in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ which is identically 0. Then, in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, $g \in \overline{E}$. Find a net $(f_\lambda)$ in $E$ which converges to $g$.

If I'm understanding this correctly, we need to find a net of $\mathbb{R}$-tuples that converge to the zero map $g$. And it seems each member of the net needs to come from $E$, which means the net must consist of these $1$-$0$ valued strings. And to keep things from becoming trivial, we are only allowed for a finite number of $0$'s to occur in each member of the net. Otherwise, you could just choose the zero map.

Can I receive some support or assistance on how to approach this problem? I'm not sure where to go on this.

Comment: You are correct, $g \not\in E$.  We show that $g$ is in the closure of $E$. Perhaps does the text say $g \in \overline{E}$ ?  If not, it should.  *Hint:* Try to do it with this directed set: all the finite subsets of $\mathbb R$, ordered by inclusion.

Comment: @PatrickR fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ we can use the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) (or characteristic function) as $$\chi_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\in A;\\
0,&\text{if }x\notin A.
\end{cases}
$$
We will work with the functions $f_A(x)=1-\chi_A(x)$. (But I used this in the definition, since the characteristic function is something you might encounter quite often.)

Let $D$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Try to verify that:

- $(D,\subseteq)$ is a directed set.
- For every $A\in D$, the function $f_A$ belongs to the set $E$.
- The net $(f_A)_{A\in D}$ converges to the constant function $0$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing that each $f_A$ is $0$ only finitely often. For example, if we choose $A = \mathbb{R}$, then $f_A(x) = 1 - \chi_A(x) = 1-1 = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Further, choose any infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and I encounter the same problem. Now, if your second bullet implicitly assumes that $A \in D$, then yes I agree.

Comment: @DavidC.Huang Exactly as you said, when I wrote that $f_A\in E$, I meant for a finite $A$. (I only need this for $f_A$'s in the net described above.) The way I phrased it, this point was rather unclear - now I have edited this bullet point.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you agree that $g$ is in the closure of $E$, then automatically $g$ is a limit of a net with values in $E$.  That's a general result in any topological space.  Namely, you can take the set of neighborhoods of $g$ (ordered by reverse inclusion) as the index set for the net (you need to show it's a directed set) and for each such nbhd pick an element of $E$ contained in it.  That defines a net which converges to $g$.

Comment: You said it best. Answers should only be accepted if they are satisfactory. As such, you can find that Martin's answer was accepted.

Comment: Very good.  I am happy you accepted an answer.